# Экспортирование таблицы из postgresql с помощью psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Имеется большой скрипт для записи данных в таблицу, есть требование по экспорту устаревших данных из бд для хранения

```
def export_data(cursor, name, connection):
    try:
        print(f''' COPY '{name}' TO '/tmp/databases/{name}/{name}_{datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%y")}.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER) ''')
        insert_table_query = f''' COPY '{name}' TO '/tmp/databases/{name}/{name}_{datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%y")}.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER) '''
        cursor.execute(insert_table_query)
        connection.commit()
    except Exception and errors as e:
        print(e)
```

Ошибка

```
Connection to PostgreSQL DB successful
 COPY 'sprint' TO '/tmp/databases/sprint/sprint_30_08_22.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER) 
catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

Не совсем понятно как реализовать экспотирования таблиц

Comment: Скорее всего указано на это errors.

Comment: Кстати что это?

Comment: И покажите весь лог ошибки.

Comment: У вас скорее всего выкинуто два исключения.

Comment: @Александр Там исключение это последняя строка, а в целом это вывод данной функции

Comment: Ещё раз говорю это не похоже на полный вывод исключения. Должно начинаться с Traceback.

Comment: Вывод вашей функции не нужен.

Comment: Я спросил у вас что такое errors, почему вы не ответили?

Comment: Когда ты уберёшь (блок отлова исключений) то увидишь реальную проблему.

Comment: На данный момент PVM молчит об этом куске кода print(f''' COPY '{name}' TO '/tmp/databases/{name}/{name}_{datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%y")}.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER) ''')
        insert_table_query = f''' COPY '{name}' TO '/tmp/databases/{name}/{name}_{datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%y")}.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER) '''
        cursor.execute(insert_table_query)
        connection.commit()

Comment: И всё же что такое `except Exception and errors as e:` откуда это вообще, что за странная конструкция?? В результате у вас получается `except False as e:` либо `except True as e:`, на что питон и ругается собственно. Но до этого он пишет и исходную ошибку тоже, а вы это всё обрезали и не показали.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В библиотеке pcycopg2 есть нативный метод [.copy_to()](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_to)

Мое решение         `cursor.copy_to(f'/tmp/databases/{name}/{name}_{datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%y")}.csv')`

```
def export_data(cursor, name, connection):
    try:
       cursor.copy_to(f'/tmp/databases/{name}/{name}_{datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%y")}.csv')
    except errors and Exception as e:
        print(e)
```